# Retrieve value based on contents of another value

Tags: json, select, jq

I have this json that i am trying to get the just the id out of based on a contains from another value.  I am able to jq the contains part but when I add on | .id i cannot get a result

```json
{
  "restrictions": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "database": {
        "match": "exact",
        "value": "db_contoso"
      },
      "measurement": {},
      "permissions": [
        "write"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "database": {
        "match": "exact",
        "value": "db2_contoso"
      },
      "measurement": {},
      "permissions": [
        "write"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When id run

```sh
jq -r '.restrictions[] | .database.value | select(contains("conto")?)
```

I get the values of `db_contoso` and `db2_contoso`.  but I am trying to pull just the `id` based on that.  When I add `| .id` to the end of that command I get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that would be to do below. Select the whole object matching the condition and get the value of `.id`

```sh
jq '.restrictions[] | select(.database.value | contains("conto")).id'
```